# Updating 'state' dynamically in React overwrites entire state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

Ok, so I'm trying to build a form in React where I can enter values in multiple inputs, then submit and have the values populate designated cells in a table. I'm trying to get the state to update using 'onChange', but when I enter the values, my initial state gets overwritten entirely.

So, if I set:

```
state = {
    Jan012019: {
      first: null,
      second: null
    }
  };
```

then try to update state by entering '3' into the input for 'first' using:

```
this.setState(
      {
        Jan012019: {
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
```

state displays as:

```
Jan012019 {
    first: '3'
}
```

completely removing 'second' from state, and if I try to then also enter values into the 'second' input, it removes 'first' from the state. What's going on here? I've seen other examples and solutions, and I'm fairly certain my code was exactly like a solution from another question on here, but still won't work correctly. Full code below.

```
import React from "react";

class InputForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Jan012019: {
      first: null,
      second: null
    }
  };

  updateTable = e => {
    this.setState(
      {
        Jan012019: {
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  };
  onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="ui form" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
        <div className="inline field">
          <label style={{ marginRight: "27px" }}>First Input</label>
          <input
            name="first"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter value"
            onChange={this.updateTable}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="inline field">
          <label>Second Input</label>
          <input
            name="second"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter value"
            onChange={this.updateTable}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default InputForm;
```

I also tried setting the input values to:

```
value={this.state.Jan012019.first}
```

to see if that made any difference, but no go.

Comment: React does not use a deep copy, think of setState more like -> `Object.assign(current, new)`

Comment: Yep, I see now. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are resetting the whole Jan012019 object in your setState.

```
Jan012019: {
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
}
```

You need to spread the original Jan012019 object first, to preserve the other fields

```
this.setState({ 
   Jan012019: { 
      ...this.state.Jan012019, [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
   }
})
```